# How to tell Ubuntu /dev/sda2 isthe new Home?

Tags: fstab, home-directory

I've used the Live CD to reinstall 18.04 in my PC (formatted only sda1). Now I need to change home to sda2.
I've edited fstab to no avail.
Thanks,

Comment: Please add (to your question) the contents of **/etc/fstab**, results of `blkid`.

Comment: Easiest to mount /home during install, but DO NOT check the format box. You have to add the mount into fstab and make sure you have not saved anything or have backed up /home that was created in sda1. Details in last part of this. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: @ oldfred - hereś the nie from fstab - # (identifier)  (location, eg sda5)   (format, eg ext3 or ext4)      (some settings) 
UUID=688f1a28-a0f8-456b-8df1-a6e76c182c05  /media/home  ext4           defaults       0       2

Comment: @ ajgringo619 - sorry I didn't see your post before. Result for blkid. lt's too long to post as comment.

Comment: $ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="70e0a196-0a4f-4612-87ed-93544b22b08a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b4c1ad86-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Home" UUID="688f1a28-a0f8-456b-8df1-a6e76c182c05" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b4c1ad86-02"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Lindata" UUID="f30a0e77-bdd6-4757-8f2b-4da34efe23ef" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b4c1ad86-03"
/dev/sdb: LABEL="LinBkp" UUID="0df6f092-478c-40c5-9ed3-acbbffe3420d" TYPE="ext4"

Comment: Question - wouldn't it be easier to reinstall with sda2 as /home?